# 1054 - Unknown column 'cliente' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
set @tabela='cliente';

set @campo='codigo';

set @t1 = concat('SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =',@tabela,' AND 
information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME =',@campo);

PREPARE teste FROM @t1;

execute teste;
```

===============================================================

```
[SQL] set @tabela='cliente'; Affected rows: 0 Time: 0.003ms

[SQL] set @campo='codigo'; Affected rows: 0 Time: 0.001ms

[SQL] 
set @t1 = concat('SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =',@tabela,' AND information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME =',@campo);
Affected rows: 0
Time: 0.001ms
```

***[SQL] PREPARE teste FROM @t1; [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'cliente' in 'where clause'***

***Why? ***

Answer (score 0):

Your select looks like this:

```
SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = cliente
```

when it should look like this:

```
SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = 'cliente'
```

Add the necessary quotes. I don't know the exact syntax. It is probably

```
TABLE_NAME =''',@tabela,'''
```

or

```
TABLE_NAME =\'',@tabela,'\'
```

EDIT: I've looked it up. According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html both versions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `'` around that table name.

What you are currently executing is

```
... WHERE information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = cliente AND information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME = codigo;
```

and that is not correct.

If you already work with prepared statements, you should give these data via parameter binding.

Something like

```
set @t1 = SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
    information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = ? AND 
    information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME = ?';
PREPARE teste FROM @t1;
EXECUTE teste USING @tablea, @campo;
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the table name isn't quoted:

```
set @t1 = concat('SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =''',@tabela,''' AND 
information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME =''',@campo, '''');
```

Answer (score 0):

since you know the names...

```
set @t1 = concat('SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME ='cliente' AND 
information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME ='codigo');
```

You missed the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

please, use ''' where varchar or text value is there, look like your query :

```
    declare @tabela varchar(200);
    declare @campo varchar(200);
    declare @t1 varchar(200);


    set @tabela='cliente';
    set @campo='codigo';
    set @t1 = concat('SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
    information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =''',@tabela,''' AND 
    information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME =''',@campo,'''');


    PREPARE teste FROM @t1;

    execute teste;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't wrap your data in quotes:

sqlfiddle! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b900/15

(the right link this time)

```
set @t1 = concat('SELECT count(0) FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE 
information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME ="',@tabela,'" AND 
information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME ="',@campo,'"');
```